# Как заполнить массив объектами класса

Tags: массивы, java

Создал класс, в нем конструктор с двумя параметрами int. Затем в мэине создал лист с типом класса. Пытаюсь создать объект в листе, не получается. Что нужно сделать?
вот конструктор:

```
public ShortDate(int aDay, int aMonth){
            this.day = aDay;
            this.month = aMonth;
        if(!set(aDay,aMonth)){System.out.println("Error creating " + this.day + "." + this.month);}

    }
```

Вот пытался сделать массивы (и через list, и так. Желательно через лист, т.к. хочется "динамический" массив)

```
ArrayList<ShortDate> holiday = new ArrayList<ShortDate>();
holiday.add(11,22);
```

Вот просто через массив:

ShortDate[] arr = new ShortDate[11];
arr[1]  = (11,22)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
holyday.add(new ShortDate(11, 22));
```

Comment: Спасибо. А не могли бы вы подсказать, как организовать вывод обьекта, а то у меня вышла белеберда:"ShortDate@69b3d448", хотя должно выводить "1122" или что-то вроде того

Comment: аа, все, уже разобрался:
я писал вот так "holiday.get(i)", а надо было так:" 
holiday.get(i).getDay()+holiday.get(i).getMonth()" (может, кому пригодится)
естественно, перед этим сделать гэттеры

Comment: а можно переопределить метод toString(), тогда holiday.get(i) будет выводить то, что вы захотите